# Building Linux cross-toolchain for Cortex-m7

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, glib, cortex-m

I am trying to run a Linux environment on a STM32F746G-Discovery board. U-boot and Linux kernel support to this particular target is quite good and at my current stage I was able to:

- Boot U-boot;
- Handover to Linux Kernel;
- Mount rootfs on the MMC;
- Call init script.

However my init script exists with the error:

> Starting init: /sbin/init exists but couldn't execute it (error -8)

I decided to investigate my binaries a little further and found out that the binary and glibc were compiled for the wrong target. Readelf on "libc.so.6" outputs:

```
File Attributes
Tag_CPU_name: "ARM10TDMI"
Tag_CPU_arch: v5T
Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-1
Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
Tag_ABI_FP_rounding: Needed
Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
Tag_ABI_FP_user_exceptions: Needed
Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
Tag_ABI_optimization_goals: Aggressive Speed
```

So I decided to rebuild my toolchain. I had no problems rebuilding Binutils and GCC, but when it comes to glibc I couldn't define the sub architecture. I have tried the following:

Running configure with "--with-cpu=cortex-m7": But the scripts returns: **configure: error: The cortex-m7 subspecies of arm is not supported.**

Defining non-shared CFLAGS using "--with-nonshared-cflags="-mcpu=cortex-m7"": configure exists normally but when building **csu/subdir_lib** I get the error:

```
../sysdeps/arm/sysdep.h:144: Error: selected processor does not support ARM opcodes
../sysdeps/arm/crti.S:64: Error: attempt to use an ARM instruction on a Thumb-only processor -- `ldr r3,.LGOT'
../sysdeps/arm/crti.S:65: Error: attempt to use an ARM instruction on a Thumb-only processor -- `ldr r2,.LGOT+4'
../sysdeps/arm/crti.S:67: Error: attempt to use an ARM instruction on a Thumb-only processor -- `add r3,pc,r3'
../sysdeps/arm/crti.S:68: Error: attempt to use an ARM instruction on a Thumb-only processor -- `ldr r2,[r3,r2]'
../sysdeps/arm/crti.S:69: Error: attempt to use an ARM instruction on a Thumb-only processor -- `cmp r2,#0'
../sysdeps/arm/crti.S:70: Error: attempt to use an ARM instruction on a Thumb-only processor -- `bxeq lr'
../sysdeps/arm/crti.S:71: Error: attempt to use an ARM instruction on a Thumb-only processor -- `b __gmon_start__'
../sysdeps/arm/crti.S:84: Error: attempt to use an ARM instruction on a Thumb-only processor -- `push {r3,lr}'
../sysdeps/arm/crti.S:86: Error: attempt to use an ARM instruction on a Thumb-only processor -- `bl call_weak_fn'
../sysdeps/arm/crti.S:97: Error: attempt to use an ARM instruction on a Thumb-only processor -- `push {r3,lr}'
```

My question is does glibc supports *Cortex-M* families? If so, how can I set the library to compile against those targets.

With glibc does not support the M family what alternative do I have to run Linux applications on the discovery board.

Comment: I am doubtful that linux runs on an mcu, but if you wish to try go for it.  even the glibc build you have should have thumb libraries that will work on the cortex-m7 they might not use the thumb2 extensions supported by armv7-m but will still function.  I have not gone through by hand to compare armv7-a thumb2 to armv7-m thumb to but you could try that route as well and use the thumb libraries.  armv7-a tools like gcc default to thumb2 anyway

Comment: it is not going to be like running linux on a raspberry pi or anything remotely like that I assume you already know.

Comment: Thanks @old_timer. How should I set the configure? I have tried **configure --prefix=${PREFIX}${TARGET} --build=$MACHTYPE --host=${TARGET} --target=${TARGET} --with-headers=${PREFIX}${TARGET}/include --disable-multilib --with-nonshared-cflags="-mcpu=cortex-m7"** with TARGET=arm-none-linux-gnueabi but that gives me the unsupported error mentioned above. Adding **-mthumb** or **-marm** to the CFLAGS didn't help

Comment: I'm posting a comment rather than an answer because I'm not directly answering your question. Building a toolchain from scratch is a huge undertaking. I would suggest to use one of the readily available [Bootlin toolchains](https://toolchains.bootlin.com/) or look at [crosstool-NG](https://crosstool-ng.github.io/) if you insist on building your own. At least it's worth reading the crosstool-NG documentation. Depending on how you build your rootfs, [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/) could also be a good option.

Comment: building a bare metal toolchain for llvm or gnu is trivial including glibc.  But something that can build linux binaries that is another story for some reason...And there you want to try one of the above mentioned scripts...

Comment: use the already built library from an already built arm gnu toolchain (apt-get install arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc or whatever)...

Comment: are you using buildroot or crosstool-ng to build your toolchain?

Comment: mmu-less targets such as cortex-m7 won't support normal elf executables. you should compile your binaries in FD-PIC ELFs or BFLT formats